# Insert or replace in sqlite or Merge Into in sql server with ServiceStack OrmLite

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Is there any possibility to insert new data and update existing records by OrmLite?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what this question is asking but yes you can insert or update data from SQLite and SQL Server. OrmLite lets you create Tables and SELECT / INSERT data using POCOs (Plain Old CSharp Objects), so to import SQL Server data into SQLite you just need to select the rows from an SQL Server DB Connection and insert them into the SQLite DB Connection, e.g:

```
var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
    sqlServerConnString,
    SqlServerDialect.Provider); 

db.RegisterConnection("sqlite", "db.sqlite", SqliteDialect.Provider);
using (var dbSqlite = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection("sqlite"))
{
    db.CreateIfNotExist<Poco>(); // Create tables in SQLite if needed
}

using (var db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
{
    var rows = db.Select<Poco>();
    using (var dbSqlite = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection("sqlite"))
    {
        db.InsertAll(rows);
    }
}
```

Comment: I looking for this: `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table(...) values(...)`

Comment: OR `MERGE Target AS T USING Source AS S ON .... WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET .... WHEN MATCHED  ... WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE; ` Thank you SO much.

Comment: @OmidMafakher No OrmLite doesn't do that. OrmLite does have `db.SaveAll()` where it will either Insert or Update existing records.

Comment: but as i know `SaveAll` working with Primary Key. i mean it's check if `ID`s property had value then UPDATE and if it's null then ormlite will insert. actually it's will be manage by OrmLite not Sql Server or SQLite.
anyway i think i can write a custom method on that. but it's not a bad idea to put it in OrmLite. ServiceStack is awesome and i always suggest it everywhere so i would like to see it's become more complete on each version ;)

Comment: @OmidMafakher np, note you can submit feature requests like this to [ServiceStack's UserVoice](https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests).